# Linebreak within div container

Tags: html, css

I use a `div` container to display highlighted syntax in `html`. I display the code with linenumbers via `<ln>`. When the content in `<ln>` is very long, then the content goes over the frame of the `div` container. I want a automatic line break when the content reach the right border of the container.

```css
#cssyn {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #afd75f;
  border-width: 1px;
  counter-reset: line;
}

pre {
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ln {
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
}

ln::before {
  content: counter(line, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #282828;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #444444;
  counter-increment: line;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="label">BASH</span>
<div class="cssyn">
  <pre>
      <ln><span class="comment">very long content that goes over the right border</span></ln>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't use `pre` then, which is actually meant to `pre`serve whitespace. Also, HTML has no `ln` element, rendering your HTML invalid.

Comment: Ok I used the <pre> for the spacing between frame and linenumber. Should I use padding instead? The ln::before tag generate the linenumbers (see: content: counter(line, decimal-leading-zero)) Is there a better way to create linenumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `white-space:pre-wrap;` in `.ln` class.

```css
#cssyn {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0px;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #afd75f;
  border-width: 1px;
  counter-reset: line;
}

pre {
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ln {
  font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}

ln::before {
  content: counter(line, decimal-leading-zero);
  background: #282828;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #444444;
  counter-increment: line;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="label">BASH</span>
<div class="cssyn">
  <pre>
      <ln><span class="comment">very long content that goes over the right border asdasd asdsadas asdasd</span></ln>
  </pre>
</div>
```